# Properties in RDF file

Tags: rdf

lets look in this example: http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin

what is difference between "owl:sameAs" and "is owl:sameAs of"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`owl:sameAs` is a symmetric property, so `A owl:sameAs B` and `B owl:sameAs A` mean the same thing. Given one equivalence, the other is also trivially true.

Comment: I think maybe what's extra confusing is that normally A is x of B means B x A, but in the case of owl:sameAs it doesn't matter which way round you write it. UI could be improved :)